# Find all primes p such that p!+p is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The question is that,

Find all primes $p$ such that $p!+p$ is a perfect square.

By using Wilson's Theorem I got,  
$$p!+p=p((p-1)!+1)=p^{2}k$$
If $p^{2}k$ is a perfect square, then k must be a perfect square. 
I was unable to proceed after this. I also tried another approach

We can see that for p=2,3 the given expression is a perfect square. Let $p>3$. If $p!+p=k^{2}$, then it is easy to see that k must be odd. Also, if k is odd, we know that $k^{2}\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, which implies that $p\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, since $8|p!$
 Similarly, we also get $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. Thus, we get
$$p\equiv 1\pmod{24}$$Unfortunately, I was unable to capitalze from here as well

Could someone please complete my solutions or provide an alternate solution.
Thanks a lot for your help!! :)

Comment: Upto $p=10^6$, there is no additional $p$. While this might be possible to be proven, notice that in general such equations are extremely difficult to solve , for example the problem whether $n!+1$ is a perfect square for some $n>7$ , is open.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire No, the solution is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there is such a prime greater than $3$.

Let $n$ be any natural number less than $p$, then $p$ is a square modulo $n$. As you have observed, $p\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ and therefore, by quadratic reciprocity, any odd $n$ is a square modulo $p$ and by the second supplement $2$ is a square modulo $p$.

Therefore all natural numbers less than $p$ are squares modulo $p$. This contradicts the fact that only half the numbers less than $p$ are quadratic residues.

Comment: Can you explain how any odd n is a square modulo p. Shouldn't the statement be all primes less than p are a square modulo p as quadratic reciprocity works only for two primes.

Comment: Any product of these primes will be a quadratic residue.

Comment: Oh i got it now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to be of help. You might like to read up about the Jacobi symbol which makes dealing with all odd numbers as easy as dealing with odd primes.